# ¿Como escribir un archivo dinamico en django?

Tags: django

Quiero escribir un archivo dinamico que me genero unos reporte en formato txt, para esto creé una funcion que me retorna el archivo y lo descarga, pero me lo está retornando vacío. Aca parte del código:

```
file_content = "Este es el contenido de los reportes"
file_name = "Report " + str(date.today()) + ".txt"
    file = open(file_name,'w')
    file.write(file_content")
    file.close()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = file
    return response
```

Al final esta función si me retorna el archivo, pero lo hace vacío.... jelpmi

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te dejare una pequeña guia que uso:
primero obtengo la fecha actual y la convierto a str:

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
#output
20181105-123059
```

bien ahora crearemos el archivo algo asi:

```
file = open(timestr,'w')
```

para escrir en el pondre algo asi:

```
    content="hola mundo"
    file.write(content)
```

luego de haber escrito procedo a grabar los datos:

```
file.close()
```

el resultado tendrias algo como esto:

[image: resultado python writtter]

Espero te ayude..!!

Comment: Ok perfecto, estás haciendo lo mismo que yo, pero cuando retorno el archivo en:
    return response
este retorna el archivo pero vacio, ese es mi problema, es como si lo creara, pero no lo escribiera.